# Public callback URLs using AWS API Gateway Cognito and Zappa

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-api-gateway, amazon-cognito, fitbit, zappa

I had a question about Zappa, API Gateway, AWS Cognito and callback urls. I have set-up Zappa, with AWS Cognito and API Gateway so that all my back-end routes are protected (using [this](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/apigateway-enable-cognito-user-pool.html)  and [this](https://github.com/Miserlou/Zappa#cognito-user-pool-authorizer) ). Every xmlhttprequest I make from the client-side to my API back-end has a newly refreshed ID token attached to it in the HTTP Request authorization header...and it all works fine. Now I need my app to access user data from a third-party API. The third-party API needs a callback URL. Say for example it is https://my-name.execute-api.us-west-1.amazonaws.com/dev/auth/third-party-app/callback. Now when the third party app redirects to this I understand that this needs to be a public route on API gateway. Is there a way from within Zappa to make that callback route public instead of protected?
Or would it be a pure API Gateway setup issue? Zappa creates something called ZappaAuthorizer on API Gateway that seems to apply to all routes. I am doing this to get a token during the Fitbit Oauth2 process after the client has given consent (i.e. step 2 of the authorization grant flow [here](https://dev.fitbit.com/build/reference/web-api/oauth2/)). If it helps I am using python-fitbit from orcas-git and Python Flask with blueprints for my back-end.